# Prolog verification of a binary trees

Tags: tree, prolog, binary-tree

I am a beginner with prolog and I want to write a predicate that turns true if the argument is a tree. I have this code but it gives me always false. can anyone help me pls.

```
arb_true(nil).
arb_true([X,G,D]):- X=[_,G,D], arb_true(G), arb_true(D).
```

the query is `arb_true([6,[4,[1,[],[]],[]],[9,[],[]]]).`

Comment: How do you test it ??

Comment: arb_true([6,[4,[1,[],[]],[]],[9,[],[]]]).

Comment: Still not clear if you need a binary search tree or if you are only verifying the structure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually, you don't represent a tree as a list of three elements, but a term with three arguments. And any way you decide to represent a tree, you need to be consistent. In your current (I assume not working?) solution, you have nicely mixed two different ways you could represent a tree.

Here is one way to represent a binary tree: an empty tree would be the atom `nil`, and a non-empty tree would be the term `tree(Value, Left, Right)`. So:

```
binary_tree(nil).
binary_tree(t(_, L, R)) :-
    binary_tree(L),
    binary_tree(R).
```

Or, if you choose to use lists with three elements `[Value, Left, Right]`, and the empty list `[]` as an empty tree, you would have:

```
binary_tree([]).
binary_tree([_, L, R]) :-
    binary_tree(L),
    binary_tree(R).
```

I'd say the first representation is the more usual one. In both cases, if you just want to check whether it is a binary tree, you can (and should) ignore the "value" (the first argument in `tree(Value, Left, Right)` or the first element of `[Value, Left, Right]`.

**However**: your example shows a binary three that is also sorted binary tree, or a [binary search tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree). To validate whether you have that, you would need to compare the actual values in the left and right subtrees. This is not currently part of your question so you need to edit it with the necessary detail.

Answer (score 0):

You have defined the clause `arb_true(nil).` but you represent the empty tree with empty list and not with `'nil'` so you need to write:

```
arb_true([]).
```

Also you need to write:

```
arb_true([_,G,D]):-arb_true(G), arb_true(D).
```

instead of:

```
arb_true([X,G,D]):- X=[_,G,D], arb_true(G), arb_true(D).
```

Now querying `arb_true([6,[4,[1,[],[]],[]],[9,[],[]]]).` :

```
 ?- arb_true([6,[4,[1,[],[]],[]],[9,[],[]]]).
true.
```